# chrome -EXT access _generated_background_page.html of another extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

is there any way to pragmatically(JS) open _generated_background_page.html of another extension in Chrome?

this
`chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome-extension://' + ID + '/_generated_background_page.html', active: true});`

works only from extension that calls it, but for any other is blank page.
I guess it's forbidden for security reasons, but I have to ask...

Comment: Why do you want to do something like that...? Background pages of extensions are not designed to be used in that way.

Comment: I understand that...but ext. manager would need access to those pages as a link

Comment: So, what you *actually* want is to inspect the background page of that other extension, right?

Comment: well yea, if user (usually dev) need fast access to those pages, to provide him/her a shortcut... not to actually "inspect" it (read elements, or whatever)

Comment: Then you definitely don't want to open the background page in a new tab, because that could interfere with the existing background page, and the background page has some subtle differences with an extension in a tab. There is no way for an extension to open the inspector for some other extension, unless you can ask the user to add something to the commandline arguments of their Chrome command.